# strcat giving segfault

Tags: c

Why does the following segfault?

I am using standard c99, icc compiler with unix. I can't get this to not segfault, and I am curious why. I am not familiar with strcat/strcpy very much.

```
char *first = "First";
char *second = "Second";
char *both = (char *)malloc(strlen(first) + strlen(second) + 2);

strcpy(both, first);
strcat(both, " ");
strcat(both, second);

sprintf("%s %s", first, second);
```

Comment: `sprintf` seems to be the cause of the seg fault, not strcat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sprintf("%s %s", first, second);
```

The first parameter of `sprintf` is a destination buffer.  You have given it a constant string as a destination buffer.

If you're just trying to print out something, did you mean `printf`?

Otherwise, correct use would be something like:

```
// declaration of "dest" left as exercise for the reader
//
sprintf(dest, "%s %s", first, second);
```

Although, `sprintf` has been superseded by `snprintf`, which is better to avoid buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

sprintf is "string printf" which prints to strings, formatted.

sprintf is expecting a string destination pointer(a writable buffer of sufficient length) to write to. What you pass in is a constant string literal which is 7 bytes long. And you're trying to write beyond 7 bytes which is causing the segfault.

```
char *first = "First";
char *second = "Second";
char *both = (char *)malloc(strlen(first) + strlen(second) + 2);

strcpy(both, first); // unnecessary
strcat(both, " "); // unnecessary
strcat(both, second); //unnecessary

printf(both,"%s %s\0", first, second);
```

Comment: `(char *)` == unnecessary, `"\0"` == unnecessary